# Find all titles in an XML with Elementree from a bz2 file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, bz2

I'm new to parsing in XML and am stuck with my code regarding finding all titles (title tags) in an XML. This is what I came up with, but it is returning just an empty list, while there should be titles in there.

```
import bz2
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

def parse_xml(filename):
    with bz2.BZ2File(filename) as f:
        doc = etree.parse(f)
        titles = doc.findall('.//{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.7/}title')

    print titles[:10]
```

Can someone tell me why this is not working properly? Just to be clear; I need to find all text inside title tags stored in a list, taken from an XML wrapped in a bz2 file (as far as I read the best way is without unzipping).

Comment: Please show us a short XML document that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Managed to make it work!